# Smack 4.2.1 api java.lang.NoSuchMethodError in class Lorg/jxmpp/util/cache/Cache

Tags: android, xmpp, smack

In Smack 4.2.1, with used jxmpp-core-0.5.0-alpha7.jar lib I have fetching following issue

```
com.deep.tasktowerchat fatal error : No interface method lookup(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; in class Lorg/jxmpp/util/cache/Cache; or its super classes (declaration of 'org.jxmpp.util.cache.Cache' appears in /data/app/com.deep.tasktowerchat-1/base.apk)
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No interface method lookup(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; in class Lorg/jxmpp/util/cache/Cache; or its super classes (declaration of 'org.jxmpp.util.cache.Cache' appears in /data/app/com.deep.tasktowerchat-1/base.apk)
     at org.jivesoftware.smack.sasl.core.ScramMechanism.evaluateChallenge(ScramMechanism.java:179)
     at org.jivesoftware.smack.sasl.SASLMechanism.challengeReceived(SASLMechanism.java:245)
     at org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication.challengeReceived(SASLAuthentication.java:253)
     at org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication.challengeReceived(SASLAuthentication.java:237)
     at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.parsePackets(XMPPTCPConnection.java:1091)
     at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.access$300(XMPPTCPConnection.java:982)
     at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader$1.run(XMPPTCPConnection.java:998)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

it's work fine when i was used smack-android-4.2.0-beta3-SNAPSHOT.jar lib on my project but after change the smack lib version it will throw above error.
is it smack or jxmpp library version issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add following lib in your app with same version code. you can download [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jxmpp) for more repository and jar file

```
 jxmpp-core-0.5.0.jar
 jxmpp-jid-0.5.0.jar
 jxmpp-stringprep-libidn-0.5.0.jar
 jxmpp-util-cache-0.5.0.jar
```

Then rebuild and clean your project. i hope it will work.